# Unity-C# Instantiate is not working

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-engine, game-development

I use instantiate to create objects but it create object continuous.

Code is here:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class instantiateObject: MonoBehaviour {

    public int topSayi;
    public Transform prefab;
    void Start () {
        for(int a = 0; a < topSayi; a++)
        {
            prefab.localPosition = new Vector3(0, a * -0.5f, 5);
            Instantiate(prefab);
        }
    }


}
```

it create object continuous

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Could you describe what you mean by "it is not working right"? What's happening? At the moment, I can't see any code to set the value of the `prefab` variable itself.

Comment: it did not nothing happens

Comment: So have you used the debugger to step into the code? What's the value of `topSayi`? (It looks like the loop condition is wrong, but we can't see where `topSayi` is declared either...)

Comment: There's a number of potential pitfalls here.  The for-condition, `topSayi`, instantiating a transform, setting position before instantiating, and setting localPosition.

Comment: @DaisyShipton, In Unity, public members can be assumed to be set in the Inspector/IDE (although null-checks are still good practice, IMHO)

Comment: @Immersive: Ah yes, I keep forgetting that :(

Comment: I edited but it create object continuous

Comment: Please update your question to show your edits =)

Comment: I tried for loop with debug log and it worked normally

Comment: if İ try with instantiate,it create object continuous

Comment: IS this script ON the prefab?

Comment: yes it is on the prefab

Comment: That is why.  You create an object, which then runs this script (because `Start()`), which creates an object which runs the script which creates an object which...  You get the idea. =)

Comment: In effect, you've created an infinite recursion.  This can be proven by commenting out the for loop and just leaving the call to `Instantiate`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it does not go inside the for loop. I would guess `topSayi` is the times you want to instantiate, so you wrote the for statement wrong. It should be like this:

```
for(int a = 0; a < topSayi; a++)
{
    prefab.localPosition = new Vector3(0, a * -0.5f, 5);
    Instantiate(prefab);
}
```

You were checking if `a` is bigger than `topSayi`, which would never be the case. therefore it will never go inside the for statement. It must be the other way around.

Comment: what is the value of `topSayi` then?

Answer (score 0):

**Revision 1:**

Having a script on a prefab that creates a copy of that same prefab in either `Start()` or `Awake()` is the functional equivalent of creating an infinite recursion.  Whenever a copy of the prefab is instantiated, it (almost) immediately creates another copy of itself ad infinitum.  Simply put, don't do this!  Have some other manager-type object to do the instantiating.

---

**Original:**

You don't instantiate transforms, you instantiate GameObjects:

```
public GameObject prefab;
```

Secondly, you should set the position AFTER or, preferably, during instantiation:

```
var go = Instantiate(prefab, position);
```

And finally, as @JackMini36 noted, the condition on your for loop is (edit: was) malformed:

```
for(int a = 0; a < numSayi; a++)
```

Comment: You have an infinite loop, which means your for-condition is bad.  What does the for loop look like now?

Comment: Also, is this script ON the prefab you're instantiating? (aka Implicit Recursion)